# Нужна ли запятая, если лишь один производитель действия?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, ссп

Предложение:

```
Команде разработчиков известна данная ситуация (,) и они работают над её исправлением
```

Опирался на правило:

> Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в
>   сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве
>   частей входит односоставное неопределенно-личное предложение (если мыслится 
>   один и тот же производитель действия).

Comment: "В качестве частей" в этом правиле = "в качестве _каждой из_ частей". Команду разработчиков поставили в сложную ситуацию и вынудили их работать над её исправлением. А в исходном предложении в обеих частях есть свои подлежащие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Команде разработчиков известна данная ситуация, и они работают над её исправлением.**

Это ССП, запятая ставится.

Трудность этого предложения в том, что дополнение "команде разработчиков" в первом предложении и подлежащее "они" во втором предложении – это одна и та же группа людей, поэтому кажется, что можно применить **правило об общем второстепенном члене.**

[§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)  Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.

Но это не так, потому что речь в этом правиле идет о грамматике предложения, а грамматически предложения в приведенном примере общим элементом не связаны.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая в вашем примере нужна, т. к. здесь нет односоставных неопределенно-личных предложений. Здесь два двусоставных предложений.

Главное отличие односоставных неопределенно-личных предложений от простых заклюатся в том, что в них подлежащее не называется (но подразумевается).

Сказуемое выражено всегда глаголом множественного числа, находящимся в 3 лице - именно эта форма позволяет "скрыть" объект, который выполняет какое-либо действие.

```
На втором этаже закричали.
В комнате выключили свет.
```

Comment: Подлежащее первой части - *ситуация*.  Подлежащее второй части - *они*. Подлежащее второй части НЕ относится к подлежащему первой части.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но запятая нужна в л-бом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Здесь нет неопределенно-личных предложений. Примеры неопределенно-личных предложений:

Стали искать черкесов во всех углах и, разумеется, ничего не нашли (Л.);

Подсудимых тоже куда-то выводили и только что ввели назад (Л.Т.);

Из церкви возвращались домой, ели пироги и снова ложились спать до вечера (М.Г.);